# Telerik Reporting inside a WPF MAF (System.Addin) control

Tags: wpf, telerik, maf, telerik-reporting, system.addin

I am using MAF (System.Addin) to display a WPF control onto a shared main form. When I add the telerik reportviewer I am getting a exception that I am trying to access a different thread then the one that owns the control. If you look through the exception stack you can see a reference to Application.Mainwindow however, since I am in a Addin the application mainwindow does not belong to my domain.

Is there a way to set the Application.Mainwindow inside of a Addin object?

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message=Cannot create instance of 'RadSlider' defined in assembly 'Telerik.Windows.Controls, Version=2010.3.1110.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' in markup file 'Telerik.ReportViewer.Wpf;component/Themes/Default/ReportViewer.xaml'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  NameContext=87_T
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetElementAndFlags(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementStartRecord, Object& element, ReaderFlags& flags, Type& delayCreatedType, Int16& delayCreatedTypeId)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, ParserContext parserContext, OptimizedTemplateContent optimizedTemplateContent, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntCreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntCreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost.BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(DependencyObject doTarget, DependencyObject doAncestor, DependencyObject doOldParent)
       at System.Windows.PresentationSource.RootChanged(Visual oldRoot, Visual newRoot)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
       at System.AddIn.Pipeline.FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(FrameworkElement root)
       at DRIP.AddIn.Adapter.DRIPAddInViewToContractAdapter.UrlHandler(String uri)
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
            Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
            Source=WindowsBase
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
                 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
                 at System.Windows.Application.get_MainWindow()
                 at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadSlider..ctor() in c:\Builds\WPF_Scrum\Release_WPF_2010_Q3\Sources\Development\Core\Controls\Slider\RadSlider.cs:line 217
            InnerException:
```

Comment: There is a reply posted here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/slider/radslider-is-throwing-a-invalid-operation-exception-when-used-in-maf-system-addin.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this configuration (Telerik Reporting, WPF, and MAF (System.Addin)) The WPF cannot be used due to the RadSlider requiring a link to the MainForm.

I have switched to using the Winform in a FormHost and it worked. Its not ideal, but it works.